# JS-C# double AES encryption

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

I would like to avoid SSL for a certain reason,
Though, i wish to make the session as secured as possible (so i decided to double encrypt the request - JS side and C# side)
I came up with a solution that might be suitable for me:

1. encrypt the request in JS with a certain key and IV (AES)
2. send the request to the server.
3. on the server - encrypt the request with a different key (AES)
4. send the response back to the client.
5. on the client - decrypt the response using the first key.
6. send the request to the server.
7. on the server - decrypt the request using the second key.

now, im not that fimiliar with encryption.
when i use the same key on both server and client that works (probably because the same key is being used)
when i use different keys i am unable to decrypt the double-encrypted message on the client.

how can i overcome this issue with my current algorithm? can this be done at all?
if not, is there a different way to simulate this?

thanks a head.
(code with be provided if needed)

Comment: You may wish to investigate something like [STS Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Station-to-Station_protocol). Your scenario would be the same, with `Alice` representing `JavaScript` and `Bob` representing the `C#` code. It uses Signatures and Encryption to ensure that a **man-in-the-middle** attack could not be attempted. You would have to modify the exact implementation details, I'm sure, but overall the idea is the same.

Comment: EBrown, Is there anything that can ease the understanding of the way to implement STS?
any ready code? (doesn't matter in which language it is written)

Comment: It's hard to say, I've implemented it myself but that code is proprietary (and I'm against contract to share samples/details of it.) [This ARPN](http://www.arpnjournals.com/jeas/research_papers/rp_2012/jeas_0212_646.pdf) journal issue has good information on it in easily-understood manners, as far as I have seen. It has no *actual* code, but it has a good conceptual overview.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you want to achieve by this protocol. You're protocol can be easily implemented using a stream cipher such as AES in CTR mode, but what do you think this would achieve? 1. Are you interested in the authentication of both pre-shared keys? Does the fact that the recipient can decrypt the ciphertext already mean they possess the second key? 2. Do you really need to send the potentially long message 4 times over the wire? Maybe you should do this for a random key with which you would encrypt the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

With most encryption algorithms, the sequence of keys used to encrypt and decrypt a multiple stage encryption must be exactly inverse, i.e. If you use the sequence "Key A"-"Key B" for encryption, you must use "Key B"-"Key A" for decryption.

You try to encrypt with a "Key Client"-"Key Server" sequence, and to decrypt in the same (a.o.t.) reversed sequence, which will not work.

A good way to handshake an encryption key would be to

- Exchange random session salts in both directions
- Use something replay-safe (e.g. a verified timestamp) as part of the session salt
- Create a set of hashes from session salts and a shared secret (e.g. the salted password hash of the user)
- Use these hashes as IV and Key

Comment: Eugen,if i exchange keys publicly it won't be secured.
my goal is also not to use pre-shared keys as it will also be known publicly if someone is sniffing.

Comment: The suggested key exchange will not send the key over the wire - and there is no pre-shared key. Basically the user's password is used to seed a per-session key. Just read the details.